# AWS S3 old object creation date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We want to find out files uploaded/creation date of oldest object present in AWS S3 bucket.
Could you please suggest how we can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to list objects sorted by a field:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[0].[Key,LastModified]' --output text
```

This gives an output like:

```
foo.txt 2021-08-17T21:53:46+00:00
```

See also: [How to list *recent* files in AWS S3 bucket with AWS CLI or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180240/174777)